# Android Drawable Shape Ring in lower API level

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I  have defined a simple ring drawable to use it as a button background.
Here's how i am doing it:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:shape="ring"
   android:innerRadius="20dp"
     android:thickness="1dp"
     android:useLevel ="false"
    >   
   <solid
     android:color="@color/lines" />
     />

</shape>
```

I am using it in a relative layout, as:

```
     <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="30dip"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/start_game"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />

<Button android:id="@+id/start"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:background="@layout/round_button"  
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where round_button is my xml file where i have defined the ring.
It gives me perfect results when i have set minimum sdk level 11 or Higher. But problem is that when i try to change it to lower api level, say 3, the ring does not appear! 
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar. I fixed it by setting the useLevel attribute as false on the shape, like this:

```
<shape android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="@dimen/indicatorcircle_thickness"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <size android:width="@dimen/indicatorcircle_size" android:height="@dimen/indicatorcircle_size"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```